# RSpec: Mock not working for instance method and multiple calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to mock `PriceInspector#get_latest_price` below to test `OderForm`. There are two orders passed in, hence, I need to return two different values when mocking `PriceInspector#get_latest_price`. It all works fine with the `Supplier` model (ActiveRecord) but I can't run a mock on the `PriceInspector` class:

```
# inside the test / example
expect(Supplier).to receive(:find).and_return(supplier_1) # first call, works
expect(PriceInspector).to receive(:get_latest_price).and_return(price_item_1_supplier_1) # returns nil
expect(Supplier).to receive(:find).and_return(supplier_2) # second call, works
expect(PriceInspector).to receive(:get_latest_price).and_return(price_item_2_supplier_1) # returns nil

class OrderForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def initialize(purchaser)
    @purchaser = purchaser
  end  

  def submit(orders)        
    orders.each do |supplier_id, order_items|      
      @supplier = Organization.find(supplier_id.to_i)
      @order_item = OrderItem.save(                    
        price_unit_price: PriceInspector.new(@purchaser).get_latest_price.price_unit_price
      )
      [...]
    end
  end
end

class PriceInspector
  def initialize(purchaser)
    @purchaser = purchaser    
  end

  def get_latest_price
    [...]
  end
end
```

**Edit**

Here's the updated test code based on Bogieman's answer:

```
before(:each) do        
  expect(Organization).to receive(:find).and_return(supplier_1, supplier_2)

  price_inspector = PriceInspector.new(purchaser, item_1)
  PriceInspector.stub(:new).and_return price_inspector
  expect(price_inspector).to receive(:get_latest_price).and_return(price_item_1_supplier_1)  
  expect(price_inspector).to receive(:get_latest_price).and_return(price_item_2_supplier_2)                
end

it "saves correct price_unit_price for first OrderItem", :focus do        
  order_form.submit(params)
  expect(OrderItem.first.price_unit_price).to be_within(0.01).of(price_item_1_supplier_1.price_unit_price)  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should fix the instance method problem and allow you to check for the two different returns (provided you pass in the purchaser or a double) :

```
price_inspector = PriceInspector.new(purchaser)
PriceInspector.stub(:new).and_return price_inspector

expect(price_inspector).to receive(:get_latest_price).and_return(price_item_1_supplier_1)
expect(price_inspector).to receive(:get_latest_price).and_return(price_item_2_supplier_1)
```

Comment: I couldn't call it twice: `The message 'get_latest_price' was received by #<PriceInspector:0x007f91c1994e68 [...]>> but has already been received by #<PriceInspector:0x007f91c85a6610>`

Comment: Ok I changed the answer to take into account multiple return possibilities, let me know if you need any more help. If you could add the code which initializes the PriceInspector in your tests it may be nicer to return a double there

Comment: Brilliant, this works! No way I would have found out myself. Not sure what you mean by "If you could add the code which initializes the PriceInspector in your tests it may be nicer to return a double there" but I edited the question and added the current test code.

Comment: Ah don't worry about it :) glad I could help.

Comment: This doesn't work in the newest version of RSpec:

`The message expectation for #<NotePayment::Base (class)>.new has already been invoked and cannot be modified further (e.g. using `and_return`). All message expectation customizations must be applied before it is used for the first time.`